# on click change the visibility to visible from hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple dropdown.

```
<h2>Nice car</h2>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to add a heading for a particular options selection from the dropdown.

Say when I select Audi, I want to add a `h2` which will say "Nice Car!" below the dropdown.

When I am directly adding a heading, It is getting displayed with whole dropdown, I want it to display once an options gets selected.

By default I am giving it `visibility:hidden`, how can I do `visibility:visible` once I select an option.

Comment: share the script you tried

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".dropdown").on("change",function(){
     $("#heading").css("visibility","visible");
      
  });
});
```

```css
#heading
{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="heading">Nice car</h2>
<select class="dropdown">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<h2 id="message" style="display: none;">Nice car</h2>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#cars").change(function(){
            $("#message").show();
        });
     });
</script>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $("#cars").change(function(){
        $("#message").show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<h2 id="message" style="display: none;">Nice car</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:none` in css for hiding .With this it will also remove the height of `<h1>` and `display:block` for showing

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".dropdown").on("change",function(){
                $("#heading").css("display","block");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style>
        #heading{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>



    <h2 id="heading">Nice car</h2>
    <select class="dropdown">
         <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
         <option value="saab">Saab</option>
         <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
         <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".dropdown").on("change",function(){
     if($(this).val() == "audi"){
     $("#heading").css("visibility","visible");}
     else{
     $("#heading").css("visibility","");}
  });
});
```

```css
#heading
{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="heading">Nice car</h2>
<select class="dropdown">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is custom message for each selected options

```
<body>

<h2 id='heading'>Nice car</h2>
<select id='dropdown'>
  <option message="nicecar1" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option message="nicecar2" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option message="nicecar3" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option message="nicecar4" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>


</body>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

                    $("#heading").hide();
                  $("#dropdown").on("change",function(e){

                     $("#heading").show();
                     console.log($("#dropdown option:selected").attr("message"));
                   $("#heading").text($("#dropdown option:selected").attr("message"));

                  });
             });

</script>
```